# Good class organization for a program which is ended or restarted by the user

Tags: java, code-organization

I have written a small program which calculates total interest, total interest percentage, and other metrics based on a loan amount, rate, and term entered by the user into the console. My question is this: I want the program to compare costs of however many loans the user wants to enter. So, what is the best way to get all my methods to rerun when the user inputs they want to test another loan? Should I use method chaining? Should I have a different class which manages this part of the program? Thanks in advance. The code for the loan program is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loanCalculator implements Comparable<loanCalculator> {

  //class variables 
  double term, rate, amount, monthlyPayment, perRate, totalRepaid, 
  totalPrincipalRepaid, totalInterestRepaid, totalInterestPercentage; 

  final double MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12; 

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    loanCalculator loan = new loanCalculator(); 
    loan.getTerm(); 
    loan.getRate(); 
    loan.getAmount();
    loan.setPeriodicInterestRate();
    loan.setMonthlyPayment();
    loan.setTotalRepaid();
    loan.setTotalPrincipalRepaid();
    loan.setTotalInterestRepaid();
    loan.setTotalInterestPercentage();
    System.out.println(loan.toString()); 

  }

  void getTerm() { 
    System.out.println("Enter the term of the loan in years");
    this.term = scan.nextDouble(); 
  }

  void getRate() { 
    System.out.println("Enter the rate");
    this.rate = scan.nextDouble(); 
  }

  void getAmount() { 
    System.out.println("Enter the amount (no commas or dollar signs");
    this.amount = scan.nextDouble(); 
  }

  void setPeriodicInterestRate() { 
    this.perRate = this.rate / 12 /100; 
  }

  void setMonthlyPayment() { 
    double N = -term*MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
    this.monthlyPayment = (perRate * amount) / (1-(Math.pow((1+perRate), N)));
  }

  void setTotalRepaid() { 
    this.totalRepaid = term * MONTHS_IN_YEAR * (monthlyPayment);
  }

  void setTotalPrincipalRepaid() { 
    this.totalPrincipalRepaid = amount; 
  }

  void setTotalInterestRepaid() { 
    this.totalInterestRepaid = totalRepaid - totalPrincipalRepaid; 
  }

  void setTotalInterestPercentage() { 
    totalInterestPercentage = totalInterestRepaid/amount; 
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() { 
    return "Amount: " + amount + "\n" + "Term: " + term + "\n" + "Rate: " + rate + 
            "\n" + "Monthly Payment: " + monthlyPayment + "\n" + "Total Repaid: " + totalRepaid + 
            "\n" + "Total Int Repaid: " + totalInterestRepaid + "\n" + "Total Int Percentage: " + 
            totalInterestPercentage; 
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(loanCalculator loan1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(this.totalInterestPercentage - loan1.totalInterestPercentage > 0) { 
        return 1; 
    }

    if(this.totalInterestPercentage - loan1.totalInterestPercentage < 0) { 
        return -1; 
    }

    else if(this.totalInterestPercentage - loan1.totalInterestPercentage ==0) { 
        return 0; 
    }

    return 0;

  }

  public void difference(loanCalculator loan1) { 

    if(this.compareTo(loan1) == 1) { 
        System.out.print("Loan 2 is cheaper by: " + (this.totalInterestPercentage - loan1.totalInterestPercentage)); 
    }

    if(this.compareTo(loan1) == 0) { 
        System.out.print("The two loans cost the same");
    }

    else if(this.compareTo(loan1) == 1) { 
        System.out.print("Loan 1 is cheaper by: " + (this.totalInterestPercentage - loan1.totalInterestPercentage)); 
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(From scratch) Put the code from the main method into a new method:

```
public static void calculator() {
...
}
```

Then call calculator()  in a loop in main :

```
while(true) {
    calculator();
}
```

How to terminate ? May like this:

```
 while(true) {
     try {
        calculator();
     } catch (Exception ex) { //scanner will throw an Exception on not valid input
        break;
     }
 }
```